# How to disable Top Sites in Safari on High Sierra

Tags: safari

I've found instructions for previous macOS versions, but none that work for High Sierra. Does anyone have  solution that keeps your favourites, but just removes top sites permanently.

The answers that I've tried and no longer work are:

- macOS Lion: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/97533/15131
- macOS Lion: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/112554/15131
- macOS Mavericks: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/157737/15131

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So turns out you can just secondarily click them, then disable `Show Frequently Visited Sites` from the menu that appears.

[image: Animation of disabling Top Sites]